# Stripe purchases work fine locally, timeout on host (1&1)

Tags: asp.net, timeout, stripe-payments

I'm using ASP.net Framework 4.8, Visual Studio 2019 Community, with Stripe's official Nuget package, v28.8.0.

I'm using Stripe Elements with my test keys to create a customer and complete a purchase. Locally, on my machine, it goes through without a problem. I can create customers, fetch data from their servers, etc..

When I deploy to 1&1 and try to do anything with Stripe (besides having Elements load up on the page), it gives me this error:

```
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 34.200.47.89:443
[SocketException (0x274c): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 34.200.47.89:443]
System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalEndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +923
System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +84
System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception) +259

 [WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server]
 System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context) +579
 System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar) +107
```

It should create a customer and purchase a single item, but it just freezes and times out every time.

Comment: This is the hint of your problem, "Unable to connect to the remote server". You are unable to connect to 34.200.47.89. Make sure your server, where you have deployed code, is able to send request to stripe server.

Answer (score 0):

After an hour online with support, they emailed me this edit to my Web.config file and it fixed everything.

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy>
     <proxy usesystemdefault = "False" bypassonlocal="False" proxyaddress="http://ntproxyus.lxa.perfora.net:3128" />
  </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the proxy server they gave me now:

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
      <proxy usesystemdefault = "False" bypassonlocal="True" proxyaddress="http://winproxy.1and1.co.uk:3128" />
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```